# How to make a single PHP page carry multiple actions?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

So, I have a PHP page. Lets call it `error.php`. I want to be able to make this `error.php` page handle multiple types of errors (400, 401, 404, etc.) I know how to set up my `.htaccess` file, what I don't know how to do is make a PHP page respond differently like this.

I've seen pages with a url that reads something like `error.php?action=404`, and that would be the 404 action.

For my example, I would just pass the number for the error. For instance...

```
<?php if ($varialbeFromTheURL === "404" ) {
?>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Uh oh... 404 :(</h1>
    <h2>Looks like that file is missi - blah blah blah</h2>
</div>
<?php else if ($variableFromTheURL === "400" ) {?>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Uh oh.... 400 :(</h1>
    <h2>Looks like blah blah blah</h2>
</div>
<?php /* And so on */ ?>
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use the GET method

The $_GET method stores variables in the url, just like you mentioned (`error.php?action=404`)

```
<?
    switch($_GET['error']){
        case '404':
            echo "not found";
            break;
        case '418':
            echo "teapot found";
            break;
        ...
?>
```

Then send users to the above PHP page with the $_GET variable in the url. For instance, if the page is named `error.php`, to display the 404 error, you'd direct the user to `error.php?error=404`.

Comment: Checkmark because good answer, but mostly for "teapot found". Thanks you, kind sir or madam. 

**EDIT: I give up with editing for strikeout. deleted my mistakes.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a variable from the URL, you need to use `$_GET`, e.g.

`<?php if ($_GET['action'] === "404") { ?>`

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for more info

Answer (score 0):

[$_SERVER["REDIRECT_STATUS"]](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#105602) is one way to solve it without URL parameters.

You redirect everything what you wish and handle the HTTP status codes in the PHP.